# PDF render from HTML and CSS doesn't show tables nor style

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, pdf, html

I'm trying to turn a page into PDF and read through [Converting a Page to a PDF File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm).

What I did is make a beautiful page on Word, converted to HTML (including CSS), copied and pasted on the VF page.

Well everything is completely wrong: no style, no table, just text and image.

How can I fix it?

```
<apex:page standardController="order" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
    <html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"></meta><style type="text/css">@import url('https://themes.googleusercontent.com/fonts/css?kit=fpjTOVmNbO4Lz34iLyptLVumN3ATOVc2BoeDKcwJhFTljiSzuFEcjsip7pjNdcnF');ol{margin:0;padding:0}table td,table th{padding:0}.c10{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:0pt;border-right-width:2.2pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:0pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:218.7pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c37{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:0pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:0pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:230.4pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c7{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:82.8pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c11{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:142pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c40{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:2.2pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:84pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c23{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:84pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c45{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:74.8pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c54{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:2.2pt;border-right-width:2.2pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:0pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:218.7pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c46{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:0pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:0pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:254.8pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c38{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:0pt;border-right-width:2.2pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:0pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:2.2pt;width:218.7pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c4{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:312.6pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c42{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:0pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:0pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:262.4pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c28{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:2.2pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:90.3pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c60{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:0pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:13.4pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c63{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:2.2pt;width:90.3pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c24{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:2.2pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:2.2pt;width:90.3pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c32{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:0pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:2.2pt;width:129.9pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c35{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:44.1pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c41{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:90.3pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c31{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:2.2pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:174.3pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c30{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:90.3pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c19{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:0pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:129.9pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c20{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:2.2pt;border-right-width:2.2pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:2.2pt;width:90.3pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c29{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:86.6pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c65{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:90.3pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c34{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:168.4pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c48{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:243.2pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c52{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:2.2pt;border-right-width:0pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:2.2pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0pt;width:129.9pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c51{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:267.8pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c58{border-right-style:solid;padding:0pt 5.8pt 0pt 5.8pt;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top-width:1pt;border-right-width:1pt;border-left-color:#000000;vertical-align:top;border-right-color:#000000;border-left-width:1pt;border-top-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;width:85.5pt;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-style:solid}.c44{color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:6.5pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c59{color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c61{color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:12pt;font-family:"Adobe Fan Heiti Std B";font-style:normal}.c13{color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:8pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c56{color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:14pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c22{color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:6pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c3{color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:9pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c55{color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Adobe Fan Heiti Std B";font-style:normal}.c8{color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:6.5pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c33{color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c18{color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:8pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c14{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.15;text-align:left;height:11pt}.c50{color:#000000;font-weight:400;vertical-align:baseline;font-family:"Calibri";font-style:normal}.c15{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:justify;height:11pt}.c39{margin-left:-5.8pt;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;margin-right:auto}.c2{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:center}.c67{margin-left:-6pt;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;margin-right:auto}.c47{margin-left:1.9pt;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;margin-right:auto}.c6{border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;margin-right:auto}.c1{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:right}.c68{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.5;text-align:left}.c43{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.5;text-align:center}.c21{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:justify}.c17{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:left}.c62{margin-left:2.2pt;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;margin-right:auto}.c53{background-color:#ffffff;max-width:524.4pt;padding:14.2pt 45.1pt 14.2pt 42.5pt}.c66{font-size:6.5pt;font-family:"Calibri";font-weight:400}.c12{font-size:8pt;text-decoration:underline}.c16{height:11pt}.c49{height:4pt}.c64{height:287pt}.c0{height:122pt}.c27{height:13pt}.c5{margin-left:36pt}.c25{font-size:8pt}.c57{height:12pt}.c36{margin-right:-5.5pt}.c26{height:110pt}.c9{height:0pt}.title{padding-top:24pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:36pt;padding-bottom:6pt;font-family:"Calibri";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}.subtitle{padding-top:18pt;color:#666666;font-size:24pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Georgia";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;font-style:italic;text-align:left}li{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Calibri"}p{margin:0;color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Calibri"}h1{padding-top:12pt;color:#2f5496;font-weight:700;font-size:18pt;padding-bottom:0pt;font-family:"Cambria";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}h2{padding-top:2pt;color:#2f5496;font-weight:700;font-size:13pt;padding-bottom:0pt;font-family:"Calibri";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}h3{padding-top:14pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:14pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Calibri";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}h4{padding-top:12pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:12pt;padding-bottom:2pt;font-family:"Calibri";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}h5{padding-top:11pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:2pt;font-family:"Calibri";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}h6{padding-top:10pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:10pt;padding-bottom:2pt;font-family:"Calibri";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}</style></head><body class="c53"><p class="c17 c16"><span class="c33"></span></p><a id="t.d107bb41bc75322205f34246da34aafe1778511e"></a><a id="t.0"></a><table class="c39"><tbody><tr class="c26"><td class="c42" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21" id="h.gjdgxs"><span style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; margin: 0.00px 0.00px; border: 0.00px solid #000000; transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); width: 211.94px; height: 100.48px;">
    <img alt="https://neofi--c.eu4.visual.force.com/resource/1494614857000/Logo_2017" src="https://neofi--c.eu4.visual.force.com/resource/1494614857000/Logo_2017" style="width: 211.94px; height: 100.48px; margin-left: -0.00px; margin-top: -0.00px; transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px);" title="">
    </img></span></p><p class="c21"><span class="c13">Pleyad P&ocirc;le Business - Immeuble Pleyad 2</span></p><p class="c21"><span class="c13">47 boulevard Ornano | 93521 Saint Denis &ndash; France</span></p><p class="c21"><span class="c13">Tel&nbsp;: +33 1 48 20 20 30 | www.neofi-solutions.com</span></p></td><td class="c42" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c16 c36"><span class="c61"></span></p><p class="c1 c36"><span class="c55">DEVIS N&deg;{!order.OrderNumber}</span></p><p class="c1 c36"><span class="c25">Date d&rsquo;&eacute;mission : {!DAY(TODAY())}-{!MONTH(TODAY())}-{!YEAR(TODAY())}</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="c17 c16"><span class="c33"></span></p><a id="t.58646c1e109cdb12b913ca0de9220261748d575c"></a><a id="t.1"></a><table class="c67"><tbody><tr class="c0"><td class="c51" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17 c16"><span class="c13"></span></p><a id="t.c03c334e2f74bd6c97489479719588a68474a16b"></a><a id="t.2"></a><table class="c62"><tbody><tr class="c9"><td class="c46" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21"><span class="c12">Nos r&eacute;f&eacute;rences</span><span class="c13">&nbsp;:</span></p><a id="t.4768f474519f58ac053f2f8488122b5538be6008"></a><a id="t.3"></a><table class="c6"><tbody><tr class="c27"><td class="c29" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1"><span class="c13">R&eacute;f Devis</span></p></td><td class="c11" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21"><span class="c13">{!order.reference_devis__c}</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c27"><td class="c29" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1"><span class="c13">Contact Devis&nbsp;</span></p></td><td class="c11" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">{!order.OwnerId}</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="c15 c5"><span class="c50 c12"></span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c46" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c15"><span class="c12 c50"></span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c46" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21"><span class="c12">Vos r&eacute;f&eacute;rences</span><span class="c13">&nbsp;:</span></p><a id="t.e7e3ea61d8d38c562cfe32c3418fb92d6f5f095d"></a><a id="t.4"></a><table class="c6"><tbody><tr class="c27"><td class="c45" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1"><span class="c13">R&eacute;f Commande</span></p></td><td class="c34" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21"><span class="c13">{!order.reference_devis__c}</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c27"><td class="c45" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1"><span class="c13">Contact Commande&nbsp;</span></p></td><td class="c34" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">{!order.Contact_de_r_f_rence__c }</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="c15"><span class="c50 c12"></span></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="c15"><span class="c13"></span></p></td><td class="c60" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c15"><span class="c3"></span></p></td><td class="c48" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17 c16"><span class="c33"></span></p><a id="t.04ae098209093da465deb2acbca7257a0405764f"></a><a id="t.5"></a><table class="c47"><tbody><tr class="c9"><td class="c37" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c2" id="h.30j0zll"><span class="c59">{!Order.accountid}</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c37" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c16 c43"><span class="c13"></span></p><p class="c68"><span class="c13">{!ORDER.SHIPTOCONTACTID}</span></p><p class="c68"><span class="c13">{!Order.BillingStreet}<br />
                      {!Order.BillingPostalcode}{!Order.BillingCity}<br />
                      {!Order.BillingCountry}</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="c17 c16"><span class="c56"></span></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="c15"><span class="c3"></span></p><a id="t.299bdca4f15aed0b9b134ba04c6f3fa5d88cce20"></a><a id="t.6"></a><table class="c39"><tbody><tr class="c27"><td class="c35" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21"><span class="c18">Quantit&eacute;</span></p></td><td class="c4" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21"><span class="c18">Description</span></p></td><td class="c7" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21"><span class="c18">Prix Unitaire H.T.</span></p></td><td class="c58" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c21"><span class="c18">Montant (Euros)</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c64"><td class="c35" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c15"><span class="c13"></span></p></td><td class="c4" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c15"><span class="c13"></span></p><p class="c15"><span class="c13"></span></p></td><td class="c7" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c15"><span class="c13"></span></p><p class="c15"><span class="c13"></span></p></td><td class="c58" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c15"><span class="c13"></span></p><p class="c15"><span class="c13"></span></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="c1 c16"><span class="c8"></span></p><a id="t.6ee5576cd14f54173d72ac93d6c9c187489b4573"></a><a id="t.7"></a><table class="c39"><tbody><tr class="c9"><td class="c52" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c18">Identification bancaire&nbsp;:</span></p></td><td class="c54" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17 c16"><span class="c13"></span></p></td><td class="c23" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c18">Total H.T.</span></p></td><td class="c65" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1"><span class="c13">{!order.totalamount }</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c19" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">Titulaire du compte&nbsp;: </span></p></td><td class="c10" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">NEOFI Solutons</span></p></td><td class="c23" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c18">T.V.A. 20%</span></p></td><td class="c63" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1"><span class="c13">{!order.T_V_A__c}</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c19" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">Domiciliation&nbsp;: </span></p></td><td class="c10" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">CIC LILLE CENTRE SUD ENT.</span></p></td><td class="c40" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c18">Total T.T.C.</span></p></td><td class="c20" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1"><span class="c13">{!order.Total_T_T_C__c}</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c19" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">Devise&nbsp;: </span></p></td><td class="c10" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">Euros</span></p></td><td class="c23" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">Accomptes vers&eacute;s</span></p></td><td class="c24" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c16"><span class="c13"></span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c19" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">Banque&nbsp;: </span></p></td><td class="c10" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">30027</span></p></td><td class="c40" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c18">Net &agrave; payer</span></p></td><td class="c20" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1"><span class="c13">{!order.Total_T_T_C__c}</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c19" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">Guichet&nbsp;: </span></p></td><td class="c10" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">17503</span></p></td><td class="c31" colspan="2" rowspan="5"><p class="c1 c16"><span class="c8"></span></p><p class="c1"><span class="c66">Virement 100 % &agrave; r&eacute;cepton de facture.</span></p><p class="c1"><span class="c22">P&eacute;nalit&eacute; pour retard de paiement :</span></p><p class="c1"><span class="c22">&nbsp;1.5 fois le taux d&#39;int&eacute;r&ecirc;t l&eacute;gal (loi du 31/12/93) + Indemnit&eacute;</span></p><p class="c1"><span class="c22">forfaitaire pour frais de recouvrement : 40 euros (loi n&deg;2012-387 du 22 mars 2012). Montant automatiquement factur&eacute; d&egrave;s le premier jour de retard.</span></p><p class="c17 c16"><span class="c13"></span></p></td></tr><tr class="c57"><td class="c19" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">N&deg; Compte&nbsp;:</span></p></td><td class="c10" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">00020011901</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c19" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">Cl&eacute;&nbsp;: </span></p></td><td class="c10" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">03</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c9"><td class="c19" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">IBAN&nbsp;: </span></p></td><td class="c10" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">FR76 3002 7175 0300 0200 1190 103</span></p></td></tr><tr class="c49"><td class="c32" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c1 c5"><span class="c13">Code BIC&nbsp;: </span></p></td><td class="c38" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><p class="c17"><span class="c13">CMCIFRPP</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class="c2 c16"><span class="c8"></span></p><p class="c17 c16"><span class="c13"></span></p><p class="c2"><span class="c13">Soci&eacute;t&eacute; Anonyme au capital de 421 430 Euros</span></p><p class="c2"><span class="c13">RCS Paris - N&deg; SIRET : 488 351 594 00012 - N&deg; TVA : FR65488351594</span></p><p class="c2"><span class="c13">Si&egrave;ge social : 27-29 rue Rafet 75116 Paris</span></p></body></html>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Important notes with renderAsPdf in salesforce: only css2.1, no JS, no external fonts/css/js

Comment: what to do: Make blank Page, add header/footer, iteration way make beautiful pdf, playing with styles and html4 features

Comment: @kurunve thank you, so how should I turn my current CSS import to a css2.1?
idea is to convert : I have currently no css or html knowledge...

Comment: Have you tried setting applyHtmlTag="false" instead of applyBodyTag? I see that you are opening your markup with an html tag and the pdf renderer is very picky about the style tags being in the correct location in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @dsharrison for this answer:
Have you tried setting applyHtmlTag="false" instead of applyBodyTag? I see that you are opening your markup with an html tag and the pdf renderer is very picky about the style tags being in the correct location in the markup. – dsharrison